# Importing data from Smartsheet into Power BI using web and not connector

Tags: powerbi, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

The PowerBI connector doesn't work, since it defaults to the IE browser, and our IE browser is locked down by our IT department (can't connect to smartsheet site). So, I need to use the "web" API option to get my smartsheet data. I have the data coming in, but I'm brand new at this and I'm having trouble organizing it. I have 8 columns that are repeating as rows, and the cell data contains a bunch of metadata values that I don't want. How do I get this so the columns become columns again, with the cell data as rows (with just the face values) and not repeating?

[screenshot of data in PowerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMamj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read a good part of the documentation in order to get used to the responses you get from Smarsheet, in brief you get a Json data structure.

First read, https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#how-to-read-a-sheet-response

Then you need to make the json connection to PowerBI like this example, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4621/using-power-bi-with-json-data-sources-and-files/